# Why does my next.js server crash and stop working whenever I use getStaticProps() a page. Everything works perfectly fine till I add it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Whenever I add getStaticProps() to my next.js page, here is what I always get and the server crashes together with it.

$ npm run dev

> ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000

> info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled

> wait  - compiling...

> event - compiled client and server successfully in 2.2s (189 modules)

> warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-ia32-gnu, but it was not installed

> warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc, but an error occurred: The specified module could not be found.
> \?\C:\Users\pc\Desktop\next_course\node_modules@next\swc-win32-ia32-msvc\next-swc.win32-ia32-msvc.node
> error - Failed to load SWC binary for win32/ia32, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc

Comment: This is becoming a well known issue with the SWC compiler. They have a special document about this issue [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc). I suggest you try these and as a last resort turn off the SWC compiler (although it does look like you already have, maybe minify is still on?)